# Json formatting, unexpected ':'

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
    "breakfast": {
        "lose": [
            {
                "name" : "Fruit Shake",
                "ingredient" : "Up to 300g of fresh fruit",
                "recipe": "Put all the chosen fruit in the mixer, unitl you have a liquid fruit shake, that as low calories and a good taste",
                "macro-review": "Some carbs, represented by natural sugar, a lot of vitamin"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Avocado and smoked salmon toasts",
                "ingredient": "Avocado, toast, smocked salmon", 
                "recipe": "Put the avocado on the toast, and then the smocked salmon. If you really want to lose fat, don't put too much avocado",
                "macro-review":"A few carbs, represented by bread, and a lot of protein, represented by avocado and salmon"
            }
        ],
        "main": [
            {
                "name" : "Banana milk",
                "ingredient" : "Milk, banana, cereals",
                "recipe": "Cut the banana in small slice, and then put it with cereals in the milk",
                "macro-review":"Carbs represented by cereals and banana, and the good fat and the protein of the milk. Totaly healthy"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Proteic pancake",
                "ingredient": "Greek jougurt, oats flour, eggs", 
                "recipe":"After mounting the albums to snow, add the flour oats and yogurt mixing. cook in one non-stick pan",
                "macro-review":"High in protein, only a few of carbs"
            }
        ],
        "gain": [
            {
                "name" : "Greek jougurt with nuts",
                "ingredient":"Greek jougurt and nuts, but also every type of dried fruit. If you want, add also some berries",
                "recipe": "Put the nuts in the jougurt, and shake a bit",
                "macro-review": "Preatty rich in carbs, due of the nuts, but also in protein"
            },
            {
                "name": "Coconut coffee shake",
                "ingredient": "Caffe, dried coconut, sugar, milk", 
                "recipe": "Put the coffe and the milk in the same glass, and shake. Then add the sugar, the coconut. Add also other dried fruit if you want",
                "macro-review": "High in carbs, but also with an high protein due of the presence of the milk. "
            }
        ]
    },
    "lunch": {
        "lose": [
            {
                "name" : "Zucchini spaghetti with tomato",
                "ingredient" : "Zucchini and tomato sauce",
                "recipe": "Create the spaghetti using a spiralizator, then put the tomato sauce, and let it cooks for some minute",
                "macro-review": "Rich in vitamin, rich in fiber, no carbs, only a few of protein"
            },
            {
                "name": "Mediterranean salad",
                "ingredient": "Boiled eggs, lettuce, tomato, olives",
                "recipe": "Boil the egg, cut lettuce and tomato, then put all the ingredients in the same recipe",
                "macro-review": "Good amount of protein, due of the egg, no carbs, good amount of vitamin and fiber"
            }
        ],
        "main": [
            {
                "name" : "Pasta genovese",
                "ingredient" : "Pasta (100g per person), pesto, potatos, basil",
                "recipe": "Cook the pasta normally, cut in very small pieces the potatos, and then put them with the pesto. When the pasta is coocked, put everithing toghether",
                "macro-review": "Good carbs amount, high in fiber, has also deoxindants"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Chicken salad",
                "ingredient":"Chicken, lettuce, a choosen sauce, better if light",
                "recipe": "Cut the chicken in small pieces, asnd then cook it. Put the coocked chicken on lettuce leaf with the sauce. You can eat now, or make a wrap with another lettuce leaf",
                "macro-review": "No carbs, high protein, good amount of fiber"
            }
        ],
        "gain": [
            {
                "name": "Basmati rice with scrambled egg",
                "ingredient": "Basmati rice, and two eggs",
                "recipe":"Cook the rice and make scrambled eggs. Then destroy the egg, and put everything toghether. It would be delicius and healthy",
                "macro-review": "High in carbs and protein"
            },
            {
                "name": "Potatoes and chicken",
                "ingredient": "Potatoes and chiocken",
                "recipe": "Grill the chicken, and backes potatoes. Choose the same amount of chicken and potatoes",
                "macro-review": "High both in carbs and in protein. Has also a few of good fat. Exelent for gain weight"
            }
        ]
    },
    "dinner": {
        "lose": [
            {
                "name":"Salmon salad",
                "ingredient":"Salmon, lettuce, tomatos",
                "recipe": "Cut tomato and lettuce as you prefer. You can choose if you want to cook salmon. Then, put everything toghether",
                "macro-review":"High in fiber, with a good amount of protein"
            },
            {
                "name":"Cuscus",
                "ingredient": "Cuscus, olives, carrot",
                "recipe":"Prepare the cuscus following steps in the container, cut the carrots. When everything is ready, melt everithing toghether",
                "macro-review":"High in carbs, but also in fiber and vitamin"
            }
        ],
        "main": [
            {
                "name":"Fish spaghetti",
                "ingredient":"Spaghetti, shrimps",
                "recipe": "Cook the spaghetti and the shrimps in different pots, then melt everithing. If you want, add basil or some spicies",
                "macro-review": "Good amount of carbs and protein, with also fiber"
            },
            {
                "name": "Rich sandwick",
                "ingredient":"Bread, lettuce, tomatoes, chicken meat stripes",
                "recipe":"Cook the chicken meat stripes. Then put all the ingredients in the bread. Enjoy",
                "macro-review": "Low carbs, good in protein, fiber and vitamin"
            }
        ],
        "gain": [
            {
                "name":"Friulan frico",
                "ingredient": "Unripened cheese, potatoes",
                "recipe": "Cut in small peaces the potatoes, then melt the cheese in the same pan of the potatoes, until it grills a bit",
                "macro-review":"Good amount of fat and protein"
            },
            {
                "name": "Pork potatoes",
                "ingredient": "Pork chop, potatoes, carrots and barbecue sauce",
                "recipe": "Cook the pork chop. Cut and cook both potatoes and carrots. Put everything toghether, and add the barbecue sauce",
                "macro-review": "High protein, carbs, and carotene"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "snack" : {
        "lose": [
            {
                "name" : "Berries jougurt",
                "ingredient": "Greek jougurt and random berries",
                "recipe": "Put the berries in the same cup with the greek jougurt. That is all",
                "macro-review": "Good amount of protein and vitamin"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Fruit salad",
                "ingredient": "Random fruit, not dried",
                "recipe": "After choosing the fruit, cut it and put everithing in a bowl. If you want, add some lemon juice",
                "macro-review": "Carbs, represented by good frui sugar. High in vitamin and fiber"
            }
        ],
        "main": [
            {
                "name":"Salmon burger small",
                "ingredient": "A small bread, salmon",
                "recipe": "Put the salmon beetwen the two half of the bread. Don't choose an enormus bread",
                "macro-review": "Both carbs and protein"
            },
            {
                "name": "Banana and strawberries shake",
                "ingredient":"Milk, banana, strawberries",
                "recipe":"Put everything in the mixer, until is a liquid uniform delicius meal",
                "macro-review": "High in vitaimn, carbs, and with a few of good fat"
            }
        ],
        "gain": [
            {
                "name":"Avocato toast",
                "ingredient": "Avocado, toast",
                "recipe": "Put the content of the avocato on the toast bread",
                "macro-review": "High in protein, with some carbs"
            },
            {
                "name":"Sweet jougurt with nuts",
                "ingredient":"Honey, white jougurt, nuts or dried fruit",
                "recipe":"Put the honey in the jougurt. Mix it, and then add nuts",
                "macro-review": "High in carbs, protein, and with a few of good fat"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to import it in my javascript file. But, in the console, there is that error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

I tryed to use an online json validator, but nothing changes. Also vscode don't show error in the format. Does someone know why? If I can't clear this problem, I won't be able to move forward. Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: `trying to import it in my javascript file`, How?

Comment: Were you perhaps encapsulating it in "s instead of 's ?

Comment: @Poss if this should be an answer to the question, please post it as such. Or are you using two accounts, and this should be a clarification of your question? Then please edit it to contain all relevant information

Comment: The example is valid JSON, but it's not valid JS. Assign the string to a variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's say you have the above JSON in `data.json` file.
Inside your js file

```
const data = require('<relative_path_to_data.json_file>');

// your code
```

Notes

- You can use import instead of `require` if you are using ES6
- Make sure you use the relative path in the require/import

Comment: Please share more details. How does this resolve the given error? Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to learn from your answer